# Meaning of "Spiritus Libertatis"

Tags: meaning, history, catechism-catholic-church

Another question from the frequent latin expressions in Umberto Eco's The Name of the Rose. Here a character is complaining about evil followers from *Spiritus Libertatis*. I saw that this could translate to "spirit of freedom", but didn't find any context for this. Does anyone know if this was a movement or group during the 14th century? The book is placed in a fictional monastery in Italy during this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the *Spiritus Libertatis* ([Free Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brethren_of_the_Free_Spirit) in English) was a doctrine declared to be heretical by the Catholic Church.

If you happen to be interested, there is a 1943 text in Latin about this movement: *De secta Spiritus Libertatis in Umbria saec. XIV. Disquisitio et documenta* by Livario Oliger, available on request [here](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/2032627).